# What is the difference between JavaScript async/await and Synchronous JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, callback

JavaScript `async/await` and  Synchronous JavaScript  both look similar and making the program to wait, then what is the use of `async/await` ?

For example

**Synchronous JavaScript Code**

```
function getStudentList() {
  return ['Adam', 'Ben'];
}

function findStudent(who) {
  const list = getStudentList();

  const found = list.some(student => student === who);

  console.log(found); // logs true
}

findStudent('Adam');
```

**Asynchronous JavaScript using async/await**

```
function getStudentList() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(['Adam', 'Ben'], 1000);
  });
}

async function findStudent(who) {
  const list = await getStudentList();

  const found = list.some(student => student === who);
  console.log(found); 
}

findStudent('Adam');
```

in above code, `const list = getStudentList();` and `const list = await getStudentList();` both functions like synchronous code.

Thank you

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: synchronous callback doesn't make "the program wait" since there's nothing to "wait" for, code is just running in the case of synchronous code ... did you mean "asynchronous callback"?

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for sharing the link, even though it is explaining async/await and promises, article does not compare with synchronous callback. thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you added some code for each example to your question we would have a better idea of how to answer.

Comment: There is no “synchronous callback” for any reasonable definition, for, say, `fetch`, so I guess that’s a difference? Please [edit] you question with a definition of synchronous callback.

Comment: @Bravo , I have updated the question. not synchronous callback, it should be Synchrounous Javascript code. Because both of them are execute one line after other. similar with await keyword also

Comment: @HereticMonkey , I have updated the question. Synchronous JavaScript code executes line after line. Normal asynchronous function not like that, but using await keyword it works like synchronous code .. hope you understand now ?

Comment: Well, the difference is in the second example you're returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) after a `setTimeout`. `async/await`, if you read that documentation, allows you to write code that _looks_ synchronous but isn't.

Comment: @Andy , what's the point of making asynchronous code to looks like synchronous here ? because then we can use the synchronous way, rather than using async/await ?

Comment: Because it makes it easier to read, basically. Promises are async. They are a "promise that _some time in the future_ data may (or may not) be returned.". You can't use a synchronous process for that. `async/await` just builds on the way we used to deal with async code in the past using [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) methods, and it avoids a lot of callback madness.

Answer (score 0):

A synchronous function/code is a code that gets executed line by line, task by task. No matter how much time a specific task takes to be executed the next one doesn't start until the current one is finished, in other words the execution flow is paused/stopped in each task and starts back again when the current task is finished. i.e:

```js
console.log("foo");
console.log("bar");
// executing this code will log the following:
// foo
// bar
```

An asynchronous function/call is a code that starts executed at a certain point in time and then the next tasks get executed even if the first one is not finished. So it gets executed in, say, a parallel timeline or thread if you want to call it.
An example of this would be having a function that logs "ASYNC" after 3 seconds (suppose we have a pre-defined delay function called `sleep(seconds)`):

```js
async function foo() {
    sleep(3); // wait for 3 seconds
    console.log("ASYNC");
}
console.log("foo");
foo();
console.log("bar");
// executing this code will log the following:
// foo
// bar
// ASYNC
```

Note that `bar` was logged before `ASYNC` even though the function that logs the latter was called first. Basically asynchronous function don't stop the execution flow and just start executing the code inside it and goes on to the next line of code after the call, regardless of whether the async code was finished or not.

There are times when you actually want the execution flow to stop in asynchronous code. Say you have a variable called x and you want to have a sum operation function called `calculate()` and its result is stored to x but the function is an online request that is executed with a certain amount of delay (for example, 1 second).

```js
let x = 0;
async main() {
    console.log(x);
    x = calculate(5,8);
    console.log(x);
}
main();
// executing this code will log the following:
// 0
// {}
```

Note that the value of x didn't become 13 as expected but we got some weird result instead. This is because the request started executing and then the value of x was logged before the request has returned the sum, as a result (and depending on how a the request works) the value of `x` will be some random object or `null`/`undefined` until the request is finished and then `x` will be equal to `13`
To fix this, we have to use the keyword `await` that stops the asynchronous execution flow and waits for another asynchronous function to end until the flow is back on.

```js
let x = 0;
async main() {
    console.log(x);
    x = await calculate(5,8);
    console.log(x);
}
main();
// executing this code will log the following with a 1 second delay between each log:
// 0
// 13
```

Side note: the `await` keyword cannot be used in synchronous context like

```js
await someAsyncFunction();
```

and is only used before asynchronous functions (the ones that are defined with the `async` keyword).
So `await` is only used **with** asynchronous functions **in** asynchronous contexts like this:

```js
async someAsyncFunction() {
    // some tasks
    await anotherAsyncFunction();
    // some more tasks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is synchronous. It's also faster.

```js
function getStudentList(){
  return ['Adam', 'Ben'];
}
function findStudent(who){
  const list = getStudentList(), found = list.includes(who);
  console.log(found); // logs true
}
console.time('sync'); findStudent('Adam'); console.timeEnd('sync');
```

Your second example is asynchronous, and slower by about a second. But, you wouldn't be able to test that, unless your `async` function is resolved first. That's why I used `.then`.

```js
function getStudentList(){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(() => resolve(['Adam', 'Ben']), 1000);
  });
}
async function findStudent(who){
  const list = await getStudentList(), found = list.includes(who);
  console.log(found); 
}
console.time('async');
findStudent('Adam').then(()=>{
  console.timeEnd('async');
});
```

You will notice that `arrayInstance.includes` is a better solution to find if something is in an Array. By the way, it makes no sense to use `async` in this particular case.

Here is an `async` example that makes more sense:

```js
function delay(milliseconds){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve(milliseconds);
    }, milliseconds);
  });
}
async function logicalAsync(){
  let wait;
  console.time('test');
  wait = await delay(1000);
  console.timeEnd('test');
  console.log('milliseconds = '+wait);
}
logicalAsync();
```

Of course, synchronous code takes however long it takes to execute, with all the code below it waiting on the above code to be finished processing. Asynchronous code allows the code below to execute *(possibly)* before the code above it is finished.